# How to Create a Custom List or Library for each and every users in site collection?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How to Create a Custom List or Library for each and every individual users in site collection? or else shall i create a common library for whole site collection and then displays files only that created by particular user who currently signed in? or else what i can i do for this situation? 
In that site collection every user should maintain their own files that must be hide from others... like my folder...

Comment: First of all, you should know that there is a [SharePoint dedicated StackExchange site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com). That said, can you describe what you are trying to achieve? There are plenty of ways to create per-user data (using profile, my site, conventions, permissions, etc...). But it's hard to tell without knowing what kind of data you are working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let users manage their own files, using "My Site" features is probably the best, because it has been built for this purpose. However, because each personal site is a dedicated site collection, you may have to do some plumbing if you want to display this content from another application.